# How does a text editor insert text?

Tags: file, text-editor

Suppose I wrote a letter in notepad and I saved it as `letter.txt`. Then I realized that I forgot to say one matter in that letter. So I opened `letter.txt` using any text editor such as Notepad, Wordpad or something. Now I inserted the letters which I want to say in this letter at the middle of the file. How does it work?

Example:
Here is a message:

> " Hi, How are you. Today i want to meet you. Thank you.

It is actually stored in memory like this:

> "Hi,\nHow\0are\0you.\0TodayToday\0i\0want\0to\nmeet\0you.\nThank\0you.

Now I want to add `I am fine` after `How are you`. How does it work? How is it added in the middle of the file? how are the other words not overwritten? What is the process behind it?

Comment: Small point; with notepad \r\n not \n and what you put as \0 is just a regular whitespace character

Comment: `\0` is the null character. It wouldn't even show up in a simple text editor, and is definitely not a whitespace character, of which there are many.

Answer (score 1):

For small files, text editors just read the whole file in memory. When you modify the text, the text editor modifies the in-memory version. Then when you save, the text editor overwrites the original file with the new contents -- so the whole file is overwritten, and the text is written to the file as-is without any references or other tricks.

Comment: so you want me to take a copy of the original file edit it and then replace the original with it ?

Comment: I don't want you to do anything; I'm just explaining how text editors such as Notepad work.

Comment: @Heartly with small files what Roy suggests if 'best'.

Comment: @kenny : Thank You Mr. Kenny. Then what is the solution for Large files ?

Comment: @Heartly paging non-active areas to disk.

Comment: What about large files?